# Replacing text in a paragraph when a user enters something in a text box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change text in a paragraph tag when I enter something in the text box and submit it. For example, if the paragraph says "orange" and if I type in "orange" in the box, it changes to say "oranges are awesome."

```js
function changeText() {
  let lbl = document.getElementById('change');
  let empName = document.getElementById('textbox').value;
  lbl.innerText = empName;
}
```

```html
<p id="change">Apple or Orange?</p>
<input type="text" id="textbox" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="changeText()" />
```

Comment: Hello, so it looks like you started not bad, now you need to search in your input field text some words/part of a phrase (according to your business logic) that should trigger changes of your text label, and update it accordingly. Can you describe your business-logic more detailed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a if block to check if the values are apple or orange or something else, then update the paragraph

```
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

<title>Apple or Oranges</title>

<body>
<p id="change"> Apple or Orange?
</p>
<input type="text" id="textbox"/>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="changeText()" />

<script>
    function changeText() {
        let lbl = document.getElementById('change');
        let empName = document.getElementById('textbox').value;

        if (
          empName.toUpperCase() === 'APPLE' ||
          empName.toUpperCase() === 'APPLES' ||
          empName.toUpperCase() === 'ORANGE' ||
          empName.toUpperCase() === 'ORANGES'
        ) {
          empName += " are awesome"
        }
        lbl.innerText = empName;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good but I would store the result of `toUpperCase` in a variable and then also use `startsWith` or `indexOf(..) === 0`

Answer (score 0):

Just small change in above answer:

```
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

<title>Apple or Oranges</title>

<body>
<p id="change"> Apple or Orange?
</p>
<input type="text" id="textbox"/>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="changeText()" />

<script>
    function changeText() {
        //let lbl = document.getElementById('change');
        let empName = document.getElementById('textbox').value;

        if (
          empName.toUpperCase() === 'APPLE' ||
          empName.toUpperCase() === 'APPLES' ||
          empName.toUpperCase() === 'ORANGE' ||
          empName.toUpperCase() === 'ORANGES'
        ) {
          empName += " are awesome"
        }
        document.querySelector('#change').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', empName);
        // lbl.innerText = empName;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

More Reference:: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentText